# Change VPN Server Address from Command Line in Mac

Tags: macos, networking, vpn

I would like to change "Server Address" property in VPN Network.

`networksetup -setmanualwithdhcprouter "VPN" "server.vpn.net"` has been tested, but it fails with "server.vpn.net is not a valid IP address."

Is there any way to do that?

Any advices will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you literally using the quotes in your command or are they just from attempted markup ?

Answer (score 0):

The command is described as thus: [1](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html) [2](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/4229) [3](http://sibr.com/info/networksetup.html):

```
networksetup -setmanualwithdhcprouter <networkservice> <ip>
```

Notice that the last field reads **IP**, and not *a name which might be translated to an IP if I can reach a DNS server which is willing to do that for me*.

So get the IP for server.vpn.net. (e.g. `host server.vpn.net`), and then retry the command with IP rather than with a name.